# C#  getter/setter pairs

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I am trying to create a property i with the following getter and setter. I have tried:

```
    int i { 
        get{
            return i;   
        }
        set {
            if (value > 60) {
            } else { 
                i = value; 
            } 
        }

    }
```

However, when I try this I get a stack overflow error when I try to run the code. Is there anything wrong with my code? Any Assistane would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
private int i; // backing field

int I
{ 
    get
    {
        return i;   
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 60) {
        } else
        { 
            i = value; 
        } 
    }
}
```

If you do not do this, your code will be kept in a cyclic state and hence the `StackOverflow` error.

Answer (score 5):

You need a backing field if you have any kind of logic in your property (otherwise automatic properties are the way to go) - currently you are assigning to the property itself which again calls your setter code (likewise for the getter) - that causes the Stackoverflow exception.

Example:

```
private int _i;
public int SomeProperty
{
  get{ return _i;}
  set 
  {
     //your logic here
     _i = value; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its this way

```
private int i = 0;
public int I
{
    get
    {
        return i;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 60)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            i = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and please follow some coding naming conventions where

1. Property is PascalCase like MyProperty
2. Private Fields are camel Case like localVariable

For More read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this piece of code:

```
int i;

public int I 
{ 
    get { return i; }
    set { if (value <= 60) i = value; } 
}
```

The problem in your code is that you specified i in the Property which was referring to itself inside the body of getter/setter, turning to be cyclic effect, and eventually StackOverflow error.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i { 
    get{
        return i;   
    }
    set {
        ...
        i = value; 
        ...
    }
}
```

In your code above, you are using the same property name inside get and set blocks.

After compilation, your code will be translated to some thing equivalent to this:

```
int get_i()
{
 return get_i();
}

void set_i(int value)
{
 set_i(value);
}
```

As you can see each of them will call itself (recursion) infinitely without any exit condition, resulting into a `StackOverflow` exception.

If you have a backing field to the property, like how other answers to this question have suggested, the compiler would generate some thing equivalent to this, which has no recursion:

```
int get_i()
{
 return _i; //_i is the backing field
}

void set_i(int value)
{
 _i = value;
}
```

UPDATE:

For completeness, I am adding here a way to solve your problem.

```
int _i;
int i { 
    get{
        return _i;   
    }
    set {
        if (value > 60) {
        } else { 
            _i = value; 
        } 
    }
}
```